# a strange popup window opens in website

Tags: php, javascript

i have a games website. in that there are more than 4000 flash games available.

Now my problem is in my website i am getting a strange popup window whenever i first open up my web site in a day that pop up appears with sometimes google, sometimes yahoo sometimes and somee other sites..i dont know how the popups are coming..

i havent added any code for those kind of stuff to open ...can anyone tell me how its happening..

My website is [startonlinegames.com](http://www.startonlinegames.com)

Comment: You should tell us the adress of your website

Comment: Without more info it is dificult to say. Could your host be inserting the popup?

Comment: my website is http://www.startonlinegames.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your website has ads or simular things on it which are derived from a url or external javascript, those can add the popup to your website.